# Is it possible to use the Immutable.js library with Redux for a ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'd prefer to use the Immutable.js library than the seamless-immutable library and I'm not sure if it's possible to use with Redux.

How can it be used along with Redux?

Comment: Is it possible to use strawberry preserves with chunky organic peanut butter for a fresh slice of sour dough bread?

Comment: The answer to the both OP and @RyanWheale is: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible.  Redux itself doesn't actually care what data you store or how you store it.  The only real built-in limitation is that `combineReducers` does expect to be used with a plain JS object.  So yeah, there's a lot of people out there using Immutable.js with Redux.

The Redux docs were recently updated with two new sections: [FAQ: Immutable Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html) and [Recipes: Using Immutable.js with Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html), which ought to be helpful.

That said, I *personally* advise against using Immutable.js, for several reasons (which I [wrote about in a Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4rcqpx/dan_abramov_redux_is_not_an_architecture_or/d51g4k4?context=3) a while back), but it's a valid choice.  You may also want to look at my list of [immutable data structure and immutable update utility libraries](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md) as well for some relevant tools.

Comment: One way to handle the `combineReducers` problem is to use [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable).  It know it's buried inside the links you posted but I thought it was worth a comment here for future readers.